# Should I use User ID and Event ID As a Composite Primary Key

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating a Database for a project.

Bare in mind when reading database design is not my strong point.

I have an event table and a user table, each user can create any number of events. My question is, what is the best way of designing this table.

Current design is as follows;

Each user could have a very high number of events so I figured a PK as event_id alone would allow an insufficient number of records in a real-world application
Hence the DB is designed as below with user_id being part of the PK;

```
event(**event_id**, **user_id**, event_name...etc)
user(**user_id**, first_name...etc)
```

However, it is quite challenging to generate the event_id + user_id as a unique identifier for the event, it seems the only way (using MySQL/innodb atleast) is Stored Procedures/Triggers/Handle it in ORM framework which I have been advised by many people to avoid using if possible (except ORM).

Is this an incorrect way of designing this table? Should I have an intermediate table between event and user to solve this instead?

So the schema becomes something like;

```
user_event(**event_id**, **user_id**)
event(**event_id**, event_name...etc)
user(**user_id**, first_name...etc)
```

In which case I can have auto_increment on both user_id and event_id and create a record in user_event to link the two (this way would require more db reads). Plus this table would end up with a lot of records.

What are your thoughts and advise on this?

Thanks.

Comment: "I figured a PK as event_id alone would allow an insufficient number of records in a real-world application". You can just use BIGINT (2^64) or a GUID for your event_id. With BIGINT, you'll run into memory problems before you exhaust all the possible values.

Comment: Mentally undressing ;-)

Comment: One would normally expect event_id to be the PKon an event table

Comment: If the relationship between users and events is "many:many", then you must have the extra `user_event` table.  See [_advice_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on such a schema.  If you have at most 1 user per event, then the extra table should not be used.  (See your first pseudo-schema.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not my intention to be exhaustive about db design, but I think (and hope) this synthesis could help you.  I just wrote it down:

**1) A table can be in a 1:n relation to another table.**
So, in your case, if user can have n events, but that event "belong" only to one user you can arrange table in this way

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,  FIRST_NAME ...)
;
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
;

CREATE TABLE EVENTS (EVENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, USER_ID BIGINT
, ...);

ALTER TABLE EVENTS ADD PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID)
```

and possibly:

```
ALTER TABLE EVENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID);
```

**2) A table can be in a n:m relation to another table.**
So, in your case, if user can have m events but the same event can be linked to other users, you can arrange table in this way, using in most databases a third table called usually a "bridge table"

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
,  FIRST_NAME ...)
;
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
;

CREATE TABLE EVENTS (EVENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
,  ...);
ALTER TABLE EVENTS ADD PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID)
;


CREATE TABLE BR_USERS_EVENTS(USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
, EVENT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE BR_USERS_EVENTS ADD PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID, EVENT_ID)
;
```

and possibly:

```
 ALTER TABLE BR_USERS_EVENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID);
 ALTER TABLE BR_USERS_EVENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ID) REFERENCES EVENTS(EVENT_ID);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, well with where I am currently at it looks like it will be 1:n Users:Events. Part 1 of your response is pretty much what I have, just with a composite key and code to generate the event_id. I guess what it comes down to is if it is ok to use BIGINT in this case, and if this is the best approach.

Comment: Normally this is used and described in relational forms. Observing relational forms rules give you some advantages.  But "best approach" can depend by several factors (sometimes you can go against "the rules").  Anyway, for what I can see, I will use it.   You should use datatypes that meet your needs/expectations: if you can forecast that your users will never be more than 4.294.967.295 (4 bytes) you can use INTEGER (unsigned) and not BIGINT (8 bytes).  The same for event_id.  The shorter, the faster.